# Perl, SQL Server use of @@IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, perl

I have a SQL Server table with an identity column, set to autoincrement.

Coded in Perl, the insert in the code below works fine, in the while loop the `fetchrow_array()` call returns no data in the @row array.

How do I best retrieve the identity value for use in subsequent SQL statements?

```
my $term_sql = "INSERT INTO reminder_term(site, name, description, localization) OUTPUT \@\@IDENTITY VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
my $t_stmt = $dbh->prepare($term_sql);
...
$t_stmt->execute($site, $name, $description, $localizer);
 
while (@row = $t_stmt->fetchrow_array()) {
    $referential_key = $row[0];
}
```

Comment: If you have no variables (or sequences like "\t" or "\n") in your string, then you can use single quotes. Then you won't need to escape the "@"s. `my $term_sql = 'INSERT INTO reminder_term(site, name, description, localization) OUTPUT @@IDENTITY VALUES(?,?,?,?)';`

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using the @@IDENTITY value since it's unreliable in the presence of triggers.

Given the example table schema...

```sql
create table [dbo].[reminder_term] (
  [id] int not null identity(1,1),
  [site] nvarchar(10),
  [name] nvarchar(10),
  [description] nvarchar(10),
  [localization] nvarchar(10)
);
```

You can rework your OUTPUT clause slightly you can capture the new `id` value by way of the special `inserted` row source...

```sql
INSERT INTO reminder_term(site, name, description, localization)
OUTPUT inserted.id
VALUES(?,?,?,?)
```